# How to read specific files from a directory based on a file name in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a directory of CSV files. The files are named based on date similar to the image below:

[image]

I have many CSV files that go back to 2012.

So, I would like to read the CSV files that correspond to a certain date only. How is that could be possible in spark? In other words, I don't want my spark engine to bother and read all CSV files because my data is huge (TBs).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a list of files to be processed when calling the load(paths) or csv(paths) methods from DataFrameReader.

So an option would be to list and filter files on the driver, then load only the "recent" files :

```
val files: Seq[String] = ???
spark.read.option("header","true").csv(files:_*)
```

Edit :
You can use this python code (not tested yet)

```
files=['foo','bar']
df=spark.read.csv(*files)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @baitmbarek, can you provide the python code? This is much appreciated!!